# Is $Z(f(x,y,z))$ affine variety in $\mathbb{A^3}_{\mathbb{R}}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, affine-varieties

let $ f(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}[x, y, z] $ such that :

$$f(x,y,z)=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-y x-z x-zy$$

> Is $Z(f(x,y,z))$  affine variety in $\mathbb{A^3}_{\mathbb{R}}$ ?

i think we can show $Z(f)$ is irreducible .If we can show $I=\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}-y x-z x-z y\right)$ is the kernel of the some ring homomorphism $\mathbb{R}[x, y, z] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$ Since $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a domain, then ideal $I$ is prime.(note that $Z(f)=\left\{P \in \mathbb{A^3}_{\mathbb{R}} \mid f(P)=0\right. \}$)

Comment: What is your definition of affine variety?

Comment: @guidoar . Definition. An affine algebraic variety (or simply affine variety) is an irreducible closed subset of $\mathbf{A}^{n}$ (with the induced topology).

Comment: It is prime in  $\Bbb{Q}[x,y,z]$.

Comment: @reuns . Why it is prime in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z] $ ? If $I$ is prime in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z] $ then it is prime in $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z] $ ? Why?

Comment: I don't think your approach to irreducibility will work. Have you tried using Eisenstein's criterion? Write $R = \mathbb R[x,y]$ and treat the ring of interest as $R[z]$.

Comment: @1200785626 ah, okay. Wikipedia seems to agree with you too, but iirc affine variety can also mean just the zero locus of a family of polynomials, hence my question.

Comment: @TabesBridges does that work? $f = z^2 - z(x+y) + (x+y)^2-3xy$, right? And $x+y$ looks prime to me, and it does not divide $xy$, so the coefficients in $R[z]$ seem coprime (hence there's no way to use Eiseinstein's criterion). Have I missed something?

Comment: @guidoar I don't think so; I was genuinely just asking. Another approach is to write $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy - xz - yz = (ax + by + cz)(dx + ey + fz)$, multiply out, and compare coefficients with hope of reaching a contradiction.

Comment: @TabesBridges.  So we have $e^2+d^2=-1$ in $\mathbb{R}$,contradiction. So it is irreducible.

Comment: Check again; you shouldn't be getting anything quadratic in $a,b,c,d,e,f$.